# Как реализована передача данными между Android и сервером?

Tags: android, клиент-сервер

Я немого понять, как сервер может делать запрос в Android приложение, ведь у Android приложения нет статического адреса как у сервера. Есть ссылки на документацию или статью где об этом подробно написано?

Я это реализовал так: приложение отправляет в бесконечном цикле сообщения на сервер - чтобы сервер всегда отвечал в обратку(так мне не требуется статичный адрес устройства Android), если нужно обновляет данные, если данные ранее не отправлялись присылает пачкой(не файлом, тупо текстом JSON. По нажатию кнопки вместо пустого запроса, условно, отправляется конкретный запрос. И да, сервер и клиент обмениваются только POST запросами.

К счастью или к сожалению я понял, что это фигня какая-то, ведь даже ngrok выдает исключение: лимит сообщений. Хотя другие приложения, которые делают туже передачу данных с ngrok работают нормально. Значит там иная реализация…

Comment: Push-уведомления пересылаются через гугл: сервер подключается к гуглу и кладёт туда пуши, Android подключается к гуглу, забирает оттуда пуши и передаёт приложению. Если на андроиде не установлены сервисы Google Play, то всё это работать не будет и придётся делать так, как вы описали

Comment: Лол, а почему нельзя также на мой сервер класть?) Я так и не понял, а как Гугл сервер определяет кому сервер ответ послал, да и как сам Гугл будет в приложение отсылать, если он даже адреса не знает? Или точнее, как он узнает адрес, не у всех пользователей может оказаться gmail?))

Comment: Гуглу не надо знать адрес, андроид к нему сам подключается. На ваш сервер так же нельзя, потому что таких как вы — сотни, и если каждый начнёт устанавливать по соединению со своим сервером, батарея телефона стремительно улетит в ноль, а гугл — один, и с ним достаточно держать всего одно соединение, экономно

Comment: Или Гуго каждому своему google service(google core) присваивает статичный ip?

Comment: Хм… а как приложение узнает когда нужно подключаться к серверу? Просто есть же vnc клиенты, там поток бесперебойный между компом и смартфоном, команда прилетает с компа со статичным ip на смартфон с динамическим. Как это вообще устроено, я запутался (

Comment: «а как приложение узнает когда нужно подключаться к серверу?» — никак, когда андроиду приспичит, тогда он и заберёт пуши. Нигде никакие ip знать не надо, у приложения генерируется токен, по которому он и идентифицируется и которому доставляются пуши

Comment: Немного о том что я реализую. У меня задача сделать программу удаленного доступа и я никак ремонту понять как мне отправлять команду с сервера в приложение и чтобы всё происходило быстро, как в чате ВК, только вместо обычных сообщений, json строки. Я нашел схему работы такого рода программ и там явно указана что сервером выступает приложение, а клиентом мой комп(сервер) и у них оно как-то работает

Comment: Для удалённого доступа вам никто не запрещает установить самое обычное соединение по самому обычному TCP-сокету и пересылать через него всё что угодно в каком угодно направлении

Comment: А я уже реализовал retrofit отправку и получение post запроса. TCP соединение можно установить в retrofit?)

Comment: Retrofit — это HTTP-клиент, а протокол HTTP принципиально односторонний, так что вы видимо изначально взялись делать вообще не то

Comment: Да, это то что нужно. Спасибо. P.s зато теперь я изучил retrofit

Comment: Впрочем, внутри HTTP можно запустить websocket (двухсторонний) и server-sent events (от сервера к клиенту), но, насколько я понял, Retrofit ничего из этого не поддерживает, так что от этого не сильно легче

Comment: Мне понравился простотой php, на нем можно сделать серверный сокет?